# Dropdown submenu wont stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my dropdown open only on click. Currently, I can click to open the dropdown however when I move my mouse to the submenu or anywhere else the submenu disappears.

I have tried to use e.stopPropagation but no luck.

Is there a CSS or Javascript solution I can use to help.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="myUlList">
        <li id="search-box" class="dropdown dropdown-search">
            <a class="menu-anchor" href="javascript:;">
            <i class="dropdown-search-icon glyphicon icon-search2"></i> Search Grants</a> <i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="myDropDown">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                        <label for="activityCode">Activity Code</label>
                        <input name="activityCode" id="activityCode" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="3" value={this.state.activityCode} onChange={this.handleValidateChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                        <label for="awardId">Grant Number</label>
                        <input name="awardId" id="awardId" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="10" value={this.state.awardId} onChange={this.handleValidateChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                        <label for="granteeName">Grantee Name</label>
                        <input name="granteeName" id="granteeName" class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.granteeName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>                                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>     
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#myUlList').on({
    "click":function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
$('#myDropdown').on({
    "click": function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: @j08691 Yes I am

Comment: If you use bootstrap's example. Staying open is the default behavior for `nav` menus. I would compare their example to your code to see any discrepancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">` to open/close a dropdown menu in Bootstrap. JQuery code for the dropdown is not needed. Ofcourse the jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js are required.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="myUlList">
    <li id="search-box" class="dropdown dropdown-search">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle menu-anchor" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
         <i class="dropdown-search-icon glyphicon icon-search2"></i> Search Grants
      </a>
      <div id="myDropDown" class="dropdown-menu">
        ...
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize your jquery as valid syntax. Try this to trigger a function on click.

```
$('#myUlList').on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
$('#myDropdown').on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```